# Regular expression to not accept . at the end of the email address in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I want to construct a regular expression where `.` is not allowed as the last and first character of the email address (example: `.abc.@gmail.com` should not be accepted). Also, I have
another requirement that `..` 2 consecutives periods should not be allowed anywhere in the email address (example: `abc...def@gmail.com`).

The regular expression that I am currently using is :  `let regEx = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@(\[(\d{1,3}\.)(([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,15}|\d{1,3})(\]?)/);`.

Can I get some help in modifying the above regular expression to fulfill my requirement?

PS: I have very little knowledge on regular expressions.

Comment: But `"abc...def"@gmail.com` would be a valid mail address

Comment: Yeah but for my requirement I dont want this specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Adding your 2 new requirements we can try:

```regex
^(?!.*\.\.)[\p{L}\p{N}\s,_-][\p{L}\p{N}\s,._-]*[\p{L}\p{N}\s,_-]$
```

Explanation:

```regex
^                        from the start of the email
    (?!.*\.\.)           no two or more consecutive dots
    [\p{L}\p{N}\s,_-]    first character is not dot
    [\p{L}\p{N}\s,._-]*  zero or more allowed characters, including dot
    [\p{L}\p{N}\s,_-]    last character is not dot
$                        end of the email
```